# How do I use the dejsonlz4 tool?

Tags: firefox, data-recovery, bookmarks, json, recovery

Would somebody mind explaining how to use the dejsonlz4 tool in very basic laymans terms?

https://github.com/avih/dejsonlz4

I recently formatted a drive and lost my Firefox bookmarks as I forgot to copy across the hidden AppData folder. I managed to recover all of the files but unfortunately haven't been able to restore them. So now I am trying to decompress the backup files so I can look inside and see if I can find any data.

Unfortunately I am not quite techy enough to understand how to use it and coudn't even understand the Usage section on github. I've never heard of the C and H files that are in there before and assume that it's to do with a programming language?

Sorry for being a noob and thanks in advance.

Comment: The .C files are script/code files of C/C++, and the .H files are the header files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `.c` files (and associated `.h` files) are the source code of a program written in the C language. They need to be compiled before you can run the program.

In this case, the author does publish a pre-compiled Windows `.exe` in GitHub's [Releases tab](https://github.com/avih/dejsonlz4/releases) – download and extract "dejsonlz4.v1.1.zip" to find it.

The program needs to be run through command line (either "Command Prompt" or "PowerShell"). To make things easier, put the .exe file and your .jsonlz4 files in the same folder, then use File Explorer's menu item "File > Open command prompt" and it should directly open at that folder. (Use the `dir` command to make sure.)

For each file to decompress, enter the command:

```
.\dejsonlz4.exe FileNameGoesHere.jsonlz4
```

Comment: Sadly when I do that I get an Error: unsupported file format. Could that mean it's corrupt? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you used data recovery tools to get the files back, then yes, quite possible that they might have been corrupted (i.e. the disk areas got overwritten by new files).

Comment: That's a real shame. Thank you very much for your help.